# How to write your own styles for RSS feeds

Tags: javascript, css, rss

I've been using RSS.app to create the RSS feed for Instagram posts. I did customize the widgets through their website as close as I could but it's not there the way the client wants. So I thought of writing my custom CSS for the RSS feed.

So I guess my question is, is there any way I could write my own styles for that RSS feed. If not, then is there a website where I could generate and style the RSS feed according to my own liking.

The reason I'm using RSS.app is because it allows you to create a feed by using a public Instagram account without asking for credentials of clients' account.

Below is the customized RSS feed that I generated from their website.
Here is a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-rain-zdx7dh?file=/index.html)

```
<rssapp-wall id="FBJdgbQhIgkwCJp3"></rssapp-wall>
    <script
      src="https://widget.rss.app/v1/wall.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      async
    ></script>
```

[And this is the design I'm hoping to create.](https://i.postimg.cc/6pLX6X13/Screen-Shot-2022-04-25-at-7-36-53-PM.png)

Please any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the API resource and build your own DOM, which might be simpler then hacking away at the dom generated by the web component.

```html
<pre id="feed"></pre>
<script>
  fetch("https://rss.app/api/widget/wall/FBJdgbQhIgkwCJp3?")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(v => document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(v,null,2)
  );
</script>
```

Comment: yeah, I could do that but would it be able to work the way RSS feed works? like, update the feed on posting a new Instagram post.

Comment: you would need to ask rss.app about that, btw its not RSS, rss.app is a web component which fetches JSON like above (which is most likely cached on their end and they have a bunch of scrappers which are crafted to fetch title/desc/img etc for various sites) then renders it, its not a traditional atom syndication format like XML so you would need contact them to see when they re-scrape

Comment: Yes, the question is misleading as it is not RSS.  And the rss.app script appears to already style the received json based on the style template chosen by the user. So OP should really be looking at the server side templates.  +1

Comment: @Yogi yeah misleading domain name, sales pitch :) thanks for +1, OP will have issues as the templating is pretty limited https://rss.app/feed/FBJdgbQhIgkwCJp3/embed?customize=wall which is why I suggested to just make own dom from the JSON

Comment: Ah, I see. Let's say I don't use rss.app to create the insta feed. Could you suggest how do I create an RSS feed that updates on its own. At least that way I would be able to style the way the client wants.